# Programmatically check if a process is being run in the background

Tags: c, linux, background-process

2 questions:

1) Is there any Linux/Posix API to know if a process has been invoked as a background process?

```
linux> myprogram &
```

Can the code for `myprogram` detect that it has been invoked to run in the background (via `&`) ?

2) Is there any Linux/Posix API to make a process run in the background even if it has been started as a foreground process?  I.E. somehow 'detach' from the shell at runtime.. (either detach itself from the shell completely, or run as a background process of the shell).

```
linux> myprogram
**** starting myprogram as a background job ****
linux>
```

The shell prompt should come right back to me since `myprogram` has detached from the shell and is running in the background

Comment: You can check the code for the `top` command, and see how it gets command names and process statuses (it probably involves reading files from `/proc`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) there are two ways to know whether a process in background

1. have a signal handler for `SIGTTIN /SIGTTOUT` and do a non-blocking read/write depending on which signal handler(stdin/stdout).
2. check the process-group and match it with the terminals' `getpgrp() == tcgetpgrp(STDOUT_FILENO)`

you will need to repeat the check, as the process can be foregrounded or backgrounded anytime.

2) There is a `daemon` function to put the process in background. its advisable to redirect the application prints to `syslog` or some other file while daemonizing.

```
if (daemonize) {
//redirect all prints to syslog or some other logfile
    daemon(0, 0);
}
```

where `daemonize` can be an arguement to the application whether to go into background or not.

Comment: Typo: The signal is named `SIGTTOU`, not `SIGTTOUT`.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your second part, that's usually called a daemon and they're built something like this.

```
main()
    pid = fork()
    if pid is child
          run program
    else we are the parent process
       exit to command prompt
```

Answer (score 1):

A process is in the background if its parent shell process isn't suspended (waiting), which you can check through the PID.

To put a process in the background (detach it completely from the shell at runtime), you use the daemon(3) function.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read the [tty(4)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/tty.4.html) man page. From what I understand, a process in the background does not have any `/dev/tty` (so `open`-ing that file would fail).

The `TIOCNOTTY` ioctl should detach the calling process from its controlling terminal.

You might be interested by the [isatty(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/isatty.3.html) function (e.g. to detect that your *stdin* or *stdout* is or not a terminal).