# How to detect if python script is being run as a background process

Tags: python, background-process

Is there a way to tell whether my python script is running as a background process or not? I'm trying to differentiate between these two:

```
sudo ./myscript.py
sudo ./myscript.py &
```

Using `sys.argv` doesn't work - the ampersand doesn't count as an argument apparently. And what would be the effect of the following instead:

```
sudo python myscript.py
sudo python myscript.py &
```

I've had a look around, but everything seems to be about starting a background process from within a Python script, not whether the Python script itself is a background process. Thanks!

**EDIT:** The aim is to output a message (or not), *i.e.* `"Press Ctrl+C to stop this script"` if started normally, but don't display the message if started as a background process.

**EDIT 2** I neglected to mention that this python script will be started by a script in 
`/etc/init.d` rather than from a terminal prompt. So the answer marked as correct does indeed answer the question as I phrased it and with the information given, but I thought I should point out that it doesn't work in the `init.d` scenario, to avoid any potential confusion in the future.

Comment: I don't think so. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I've added to the original request to clarify.

Comment: When the process is detached, reading from `stdin` will block it. Writing to `stdout` works, though. I don't know a way to check whether reading `stdin` would block, though.

Comment: Answer for C code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894261/programmatically-check-if-a-process-is-being-run-in-the-background

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking for interactive shell in a Python script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108330/checking-for-interactive-shell-in-a-python-script)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on [the answer for C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894261/programmatically-check-if-a-process-is-being-run-in-the-background) @AaronDigulla pointed to in a comment:

```
import os
import sys


def main():
    if os.getpgrp() == os.tcgetpgrp(sys.stdout.fileno()):
        print 'Running in foreground.'
    else:
        print 'Running in background.'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Example given above worked perfectly, to a degree.   :)   I'm actually running the script using a script in /etc/init.d on Linux, rather than through a terminal. The example given works brilliantly when I start the Python script at a terminal prompt, but fails with `OSError: [Errno 25] Inappropriate ioctl for device` when run via the init.d script. I'll keep looking!  :)

Comment: Wrap the call to `os.tcgetpgrp` in a try/except block and if throws an  `OSError` then you know `sys.stdout` isn't a terminal. In that case it's probably safe to assume that no one is going to be able read the message. CTRL-C probably also won't work.

Comment: Technically, calling "nohup python code.py > output_file.txt" is not running the code in background, but this answer tells me so.

Answer (score 2):

I saw the other solutions on other and decided to write a pure python solution. It reads from `/proc/<pid>/stat` rather than calling a subprocess.

```
from os import getpid

with open("/proc/{}/stat".format(getpid())) as f:
    data = f.read()

foreground_pid_of_group = data.rsplit(" ", 45)[1]
is_in_foreground = str(getpid()) == foreground_pid_of_group
```

The meanings of the columns of the stat file can be found [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man5/proc.5.html)

Answer (score 1):

Based on bash solution from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118468) answer:

```
import os
import subprocess
pid = os.getpid()
if "+" in subprocess.check_output(["ps", "-o", "stat=", "-p", str(pid)]):
  print "Running in foreground"
else:
  print "Running in background"
```

Comment: I get this error: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'