# From a C program, how to know if the process is running in the foreground or background?

Tags: c, process, posix

In my C program, I want to have different behavior whether my process (POSIX) is running in the background or in the foreground. **I don't have access to argc/argv**.

I was thinking about something in the likes of:

```
if (isatty(0)) {
  printf("Foreground\n");
} else {
  printf("Background\n");
}
```

But this isn't working well for me. I get the following result:

```
$ ./myprog &
Foreground
```

Comment: I don't think there is a portable way of finding that out. Specific operating systems may have means of finding out but they won't be cross platform. Perhaps if you explain why you need to know, somebody can suggest an alternative.

Comment: There is a good explanation which works on linux, but I have no idea whether it works on posix standards:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894261/programmatically-check-if-a-process-is-being-run-in-the-background

Comment: And how will you handle being switched from foreground to background, or from background to foreground?

Comment: Looks like that linked question may be a duplicate.  The `getpgrp() == tcgetpgrp(0)` suggestion from an answer to that question is POSIX.1-2001 conformant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) of `isatty()` clearly indicates that the function `test whether a file descriptor refers to a terminal`. When you pass '0' as a argument, it mostly refers to STDIN, so isatty() will always return TRUE, that means you code behaves like

```
if (TRUE) {
  printf("Foreground\n");
} else {
  printf("Background\n");
}
```

As indicated by the comments, the correct way to check foreground vs background process is like this code

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
pid_t console_pid = tcgetpgrp(STDOUT_FILENO);
pid_t my_pid = getpgrp();
if(console_pid == my_pid)
   printf("process foregrounded\n");
else
   printf("process backgrounded\n");
return 0;
}
```

Here is the output on my ubuntu machine

```
ubuntu@4w28n62:~$ ./a.out
process foregrounded
ubuntu@4w28n62:~$ ./a.out &
[1] 4814
ubuntu@4w28n62:~$ process backgrounded

[1]+  Done                    ./a.out
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought isatty(0) would test if the process's stdin was a tty. As in sometimes you can redirect those in- and outputs. I'll test that solution tomorrow, keep you updated.

Comment: File descriptor 0 is stdin.  It doesn't "mostly" refer to stdin, it is stdin, they're synonyms.  Furthermore, stdin isn't always a terminal.

Comment: If this is to work correctly, then you need to open a file descriptor to /dev/tty first, since otherwise any redirection of the standard file handles will make tcgetgrp return -1. So, in order to get all the facts on the table, you need to use both isatty and the test for tcgetgrp with an independent file handle, to determine exactly what kind of foreground state your process has.